# How to make predictions on test image after training inception model from scratch on custom dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset

I just finished training inceptionv3 from scratch on my custom dataset(1675 train images, 400 validation images, 2 classes):

1. I don't know how to make predictions on my test images using my newly trained model.(where to point label_image.py for model)
2. Where did my newly trained model got saved?
   Following some metadata about my setup/run:---
3. I got following files generated in train_dir:

   - events.out.tfevents.1481980070.airig-Inspiron-7559(4.9GB)
   - graph.pbtxt(18.5MB)
   - and a bunch of **model.ckpt-*.meta and model.ckpt-*.index** files

After running train script I got:-

```
....
INFO:tensorflow:Stopping Training.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
```

**After running eval script I got:--**

```
.....
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [0/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [1/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [2/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [3/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [5/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [5/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [6/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [7/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [8/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [9/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [10/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [11/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [13/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [13/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [14/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [15/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [16/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [17/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [18/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [19/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [20/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [21/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [22/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [23/25]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [25/25]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/Recall@5[1]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/Accuracy[1]
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2016-12-19-03:59:04
```

Comment: Could you please point to your training script and the training command?

Answer (score 0):

> Where did my newly trained model got saved?

Your complete TensorFlow graph (i.e. all variables, operations, collection etc.) are saved in the `.meta` file. The `.cpkt` file is a checkpoint file. This file contains all the values of the weights, biases, gradients and all other variables.

> I don't know how to make predictions on my test images using my newly trained model.(where to point label_image.py for model)

To restore your trained model use:

```
withth tf.Session() as sess:    
   saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my-model-1000.meta')
   saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

Note that the name of the layer is set. For example:

```
out_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_1, units=6, name='prediction')
```

Now you can use it for your prediction:

```
sess.run(prediction, feed_dict)
```

Where prediction is the name of the output variable of the last layer of your net.

Answer (score 0):

In general case:

1. the model is saved as checkpoint files ( model.ckpt)
2. you can load the model by passing the path of it as an argument for the saver object along with the session: `Saver.restore(sess, "path to you model.ckpt files")`
3. because you are restoring the model, do not initialize the global variables,DO NOT DO : `sess.run(tf.globale_variables_intializer().init())`
4. after restoring your model, just do the following: `Sess.run(prediction, feed-dict{your input image here})`
5. since it is a 2 class classification as you mentioned, the output of 5 should be  a vector of 2 dimensions, example [0.22331, -23.21] which represents the probability of which class is your image, so you just need to run using numpy for example : np.argmax([0.22331,-23.21] ) and that will give you the index of the first element because the first element is bigger than the second which means there is a higher probability of your image being from the first class.